# Android SwipeRefreshLayout shows twice in Fragment using support library

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

It seems like a support library bug, but when i make mSwipeRefreshLayout refreshing in fragment onCreateView using this code

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

      }
});
```

circle progress starts twice. First it appears and immediately hides and then appears again and then works like it supposed to do.
It doesn't happen on Android L devices, only when api < 21 with using support library.
Please help me out.

Comment: I think we need to see more of the code.